# NP languages definition

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Is it good to define a language $\mathcal{L}$ in NP as a language for which, given an element $x$, it is possible in polynomial-time to check whether $x \in \mathcal{L}$ or not?
Because I need to have an informal definition of that, in order to give just an idea of it, without using formalism.
Otherwise how could I define it roughly speaking?

Comment: "Because I need to have an informal definition of that, in order to give just an idea of it, without using formalism" -- to whom? In my experience, sticking to the definition is the better approach for most people.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it good to define a language $\mathcal{L}$ in NP as a language for
>   which, given an element $x$, it is possible in polynomial-time to
>   check whether $x \in \mathcal{L}$ or not?

**No.** If you could do that you could "check" that this language would be in P, because you can check (or more formally *decide*) all possible words for membership in polynomial time this way.

A correct formulation would be:

> A language $\mathcal L$ is in NP if for every word $x$ in the language there exists a *witness* $w$ which is of length polynomial in the length of $x$ and given the witness and the word you
>   can verify language-membership in polynomial time.

Note that you only need said witness (sometimes also called *certificate*) need only exist for words that actually are in the language, i.e. you don't need to be able to construct them for negative instances and constructing them is allowed to take super-polynomial time.

Answer (score 7):

No! The definition you give is the definition of **P**!

**NP** is the class of languages $\mathcal{L}$ where given $x$ and what you might call a "proof" $y$, you can deterministically check in time polynomial in the size of $x$ and $y$ whether $y$ really does prove that $x\in\mathcal{L}$. In addition, the size of $y$ must be bounded by some polynomial in the size of $x$.

Examples of proofs would be satisfying assignments for $\text{SAT}$, colourings for $3\text{-COL}$, and so on. These proofs are more commonly called "certificates" or "witnesses".

The key distinction is that the language itself is a yes/no decision problem (e.g., "Is this formula satisfiable?"), whereas the proof tends to be a solution to the related function problem (e.g., "Give me a satisfying assignment for this formula, if it has one.").